# Efficiency of Random Method

Tags: java, random, instance, performance

I recently read that you do not want to make new instances when unnecessary.  I am not sure if I understand what it was saying.  The problem was the repeat of this in LogCat:

```
08-09 17:12:11.300: D/dalvikvm(19620): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2281K, 23% free 9365K/12048K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
```

So is it better to have this method:

```
public int rand(int i) {
    int rand = new Random().nextInt(i);
    return rand;
}
```

than to have this method:

```
public int rand(int i) {
    return new Random().nextInt(i);
}
```

if you are calling rand() a lot?  Why or why not?  Thanks for helping the newb!

Comment: I don't think you quite understood what you read. Both examples you show are the exact same thing and create a new instance of `Random`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```
class ... {

  private final Random dice = new Random();

  public int rand(int i) {
    return dice.nextInt(i);
  }

}
```

That way, you are calling `new Random()` only once, instead of every time you generate a number.

Comment: It will work without it, but instance variables should be `final` unless you *need* to change their value. It's just good practice.

Comment: It work just fine, but you can't assign a new Random instance there(shouldn't need to do this anyway).

Answer (score 4):

I'd bet those two methods will generate identical bytecode. What you actually want to achieve is to have one instance of `Random`, and just call `nextInts` from that instance, as to not reset the seed all the time.

Comment: ty. i dont quite understand what u mean thought. can u try explaining it differently please?  if i only had one instance of random, would it not be the same number repeatedly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816952/java-advantage-of-using-static-variable-in-java This questions has some relevance. Do note, that both of the methods you posted most likely end up 100% identical when compiled.

Comment: The `Random` object maintains internal state so that it'll return a different number each time.

Comment: im not familiar with internal state, so i guess i should do some more research. thanks for help everyone. not quite sure why i got the downvote though. guess cuz the answer was too obvious to that person

Comment: The internal state(same seed) is important if you care about determinism.

Comment: is it possible to only have one instance of Random given that every time i call it, its from a different number of chioces?  for example, the first time i call, i may want random between 1 and 10, and then 1 and 5 the next time

Answer (score 1):

Performance is merely incidental here. If you are creating a new `Random` object on every call, not only are you wasting time, but you're not getting random numbers at all. You MUST create the `Random` object only once to create a generator, after which calling various `next...` functions on it will produce random numbers from that generator. That's how random number generators work.

Answer (score -2):

It looks to me like you're making things more complicated than they need to be.  Instead of calling a method that creates a Random object and returns a new random number, just create a Random object in the method that called your rand(int i) method.  For example, instead of doing this:

```
public void someMethod()
{
    int randomInt = rand(5);
}
```

Do this:

```
public void someMethodImproved()
{
    Random randObject = new Random();
    int randInt = randObject.nextInt(5);
}
```

You can then continue to call randObject.nextInt(5) for as long as you want, and it will continue to give you pseudo-random integers between 0 (inclusive) and 5 (exclusive).